# Why is this query returning undefined?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query returns undefined when i try to filter the other tables out. When i run the query without the where statement it return all tables including the one i just created with the table_schema clearly labeled public. But when i try to filter them out it comes back as undefined. This is my first time using postgres

```
CREATE TABLE category_description(
       category_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      category_name VARCHAR(20),
      rental_rate NUMERIC  (4,2),
      last_update TIMESTAMP
    );
    
    
    
    SELECT table_schema, table_name 
    from information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = "public"; 

    Query Error: error: column "public" does not exist

table_schema    table_name
public          category_description
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes are used in Postgres to escape database identifiers (such as a column or table name).  Use single quotes for string literals.  The following version should work:

```sql
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public';
```

The exact error message you are seeing indicates that Postgres thinks that `"public"` is the name of a column.